# RxJS takeUntil not working while trying to compose pointer events

Tags: reactjs, rxjs

I am trying to create some streams that would represent some custom gesture events such as hold and swipe. I have run into an issue with `takeUntil` while trying to implement a hold stream.

The basic concept is that I create 3 streams of pointer down/move/ups and compose these to create new streams.

The hold stream should fire whenever a down event is made and there is no significant movement or up event within 500ms.

The relevant code for this is as follows.

```
// will fire once whenever there is significant movement after a down event
const drag_start_s = down_s.pipe(
  switchMap(down_e =>
    move_s.pipe(
      filter(move_e => {
        return distance(eventPosition(move_e), eventPosition(down_e)) < 30
      }),
      take(1),
    ),
  ),
)

const hold_s = down_s.pipe(
  switchMap(() =>
    timer(500).pipe(
      takeUntil(drag_start_s), // this never works
      takeUntil(up_s),
    ),
  ),
)
```

If you try hold the pointer down on the grey rectangle you'll see a hold event fire after 500ms.

If you lift up too early, it will be canceled by `takeUntil(up_s)`.

But if you move around and trigger a `drag_start_s` the hold doesn't get cancelled, `takeUntil(drag_start_s)` doesn't work. You can even see the drag event fire in the console before the hold, yet the hold does not get cancelled.

I'm not sure why this is happening.

The rest of the code is below and a working [codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/7mv58lzolq)

```
import React, { useMemo, useEffect } from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
import { Subject, timer } from "rxjs"
import { takeUntil, switchMap, take, filter } from "rxjs/operators"

const distance = ([x1, y1], [x2, y2]) =>
  Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2) + Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2))

const eventPosition = e => [e.clientX, e.clientY]

function App() {
  const down_s = useMemo(() => new Subject(), [])
  const up_s = useMemo(() => new Subject(), [])
  const move_s = useMemo(() => new Subject(), [])

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscriptions = []

    const drag_start_s = down_s.pipe(
      switchMap(down_e =>
        move_s.pipe(
          filter(move_e => {
            return distance(eventPosition(move_e), eventPosition(down_e)) < 30
          }),
          take(1),
        ),
      ),
    )

    const hold_s = down_s.pipe(
      switchMap(() =>
        timer(500).pipe(
          takeUntil(drag_start_s),
          takeUntil(up_s),
        ),
      ),
    )

    subscriptions.push(drag_start_s.subscribe(() => console.log("drag start")))
    subscriptions.push(hold_s.subscribe(() => console.log("Hold")))

    return () => subscriptions.forEach(sub => sub.unsubscribe())
  }, [])

  return (
    <div
      onPointerDown={e => {
        e.persist()
        down_s.next(e)
      }}
      onPointerUp={e => {
        e.persist()
        up_s.next(e)
      }}
      onPointerMove={e => {
        e.persist()
        move_s.next(e)
      }}
      style={{
        height: 100,
        width: 200,
        background: "grey",
        border: "1px solid black",
      }}
    >
      Interact with me
    </div>
  )
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root")
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement)
```